# expected identifier before new in std::shared_ptr<>

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, new-operator

I am getting an error by using shared pointer in 'Serializer' Class.

Here is my detailed error:

```
 client.h:28:52: error: expected identifier before new
 std::shared_ptr<Serializer> serializerObj2(new Serializer);
                                                ^
 client.h:28:52: error: expected , or .. before new
```

Here is my minimal code:

```
std::shared_ptr<Serializer> serializerObj2(new Serializer);
```

Here is my expanded code:

```
#include "serializer.h" 
#include<iostream>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<thread>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
#include<utility>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include<memory>

namespace TCP
{    
class Client
{
public:
    void start();
private:

    int networkSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    std::shared_ptr<Serializer> serializerObj2(new Serializer);
    std::shared_ptr<Serializer> serializerObj=std::make_shared<Serializer>();

    bool checkConnection();
    std::pair<bool,std::string>getFile();
    void sendMessage();
    void setMessage();
}; 
}//closes namespace `
```

Here is my Serializer h file:

```
#ifndef D_SERIALIZER_H
#define D_SERIALIZER_H
#include<iostream>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<string>
namespace TCP
{
class Serializer
{

public:
    //sender
    void addIntToStream(int);
    void addStringToStream(std::string);
    void addCharToStream(char);
    std::pair<bool,const char*>getStream(size_t requestSize_);
    void delStream(size_t deleteSize_);

    //receiver
    void addByteToStream(const char*,size_t);
    std::pair<bool,int> retrieveIntFromStream();
    std::pair<bool,char> retrieveCharFromStream();
    std::pair<bool,std::string> retrieveStringFromStream(int);

    Serializer()
    {
        _stream="";
        _it=_stream.begin();
    }

private:
    std::string _stream;
    std::string::iterator _it;
};

}    //closes namespace
#endif
```

Comment: 1) the minimum in [mcve] stands for "minimum required to reproduce the error" 2) this is not C

Comment: Please produce a [mcve]. A super minimal example, [like this one](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Gk5ksZQMKrg6NbMn) compiles just fine.

Comment: You are wasting everyone's time here, by playing games and posting fantasy code instead of real code. And then editing your question after it's been pointed out to you (as can be clearly seen in the edit history). I deleted my answer, and voting your question to be closed as off-topic. Please don't waste the time of people who were only trying to help you, by posting fantasy code instead of real code. Fail.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Sorry, I didnt mean to waste your time. It all caused because I am new to stackOverflow. I wish I could get the answer.

Comment: And  I edited because, I forgot to add that part of code

Comment: @SamVarshavchik A new user should edit their question when the comments point out improper usage of the site. Nobody should delete answers out of spite. Please don't engage in behavior that is not helping the community.

Comment: @patatahooligan - this is not the case of a typo, or a formatting issue. That's what editing a question is for. It is not to add fundamentally important information that was intentionally omitted from the original question, for some unknown reason, and what should've been there originally, and which now fundamentally changes the meaning of the original question. The answer was deleted because it simply does not apply to the fundamentally different question any more.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Fair enough. I misunderstood your comment as deleting the answer out of annoyance.

Comment: A note to the OP, a MCVE is a small program that still reproduces the error. Create one, maybe using http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com and test that is still demonstrates the problem, before posting. In this process, you often discover the solution yourself :)

Answer (score 5):

```
class Serializer
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Serializer> serializerObj2(new Serializer);
```

This is a variable **declaration** in a class. 
Traditionally, they can only be initialized in the constructor. 
However, since C++11, they can also be initialized using the

```
type var = value;
```

syntax. You cannot use parenthesis there, since that would get parsed
as a function declaration. So change it to:

```
std::shared_ptr<Serializer> serializerObj2 = new Serializer;
```

Comment: You can use braces also, `std::shared_ptr<Serializer> serializerObj2{new Serializer};`